# Can't change colour of text with CSS in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add colour style into `<div>` tags.

This only works when using property:

```
`background-color`: orange;
```

But I want it should be changed only text, not the background.

Like this:

```
`color`: orange;
```

In this demo, don't need Javascript still working.

My demo at here:

```js
function firefoxFix() {
  
    if ( /firefox/.test( window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase() ) ) {
        
        var tds = document.getElementsByTagName( 'td' );
        
        for( var index = 0; index < tds.length; index++ ) {
            tds[index].innerHTML = '<div class="ff-fix">' + tds[index].innerHTML + '</div>';                     
        };
        
        var style = '<style>'
            + 'td { padding: 0 !important; }' 
            + 'td:hover::before, td:hover::after { background-color: transparent !important; }'
            + '</style>';
        document.head.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeEnd', style );
        
    };
    
};

firefoxFix();
```

```css
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}

td, th, .ff-fix {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

td:hover::after,
.ff-fix:hover::after { 
    background-color: orange;
    content: '\00a0';  
    height: 10000px;    
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;  
    top: -5000px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;        
}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>

    <tr>
        <td>20</td><td>21</td><td>23</td><td>25</td><td>27</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>18</td><td>20</td><td>22</td><td>24</td><td>26</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>17</td><td>19</td><td>21</td><td>23</td><td>25</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>16</td><td>18</td><td>20</td><td>22</td><td>24</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks.

Comment: CSS was designed by Americans who don't know how to spell "colour", so the property name is `color`.

Comment: You want to set `color` instead of `background`?

Comment: Yes, I want to set `color` of text instead of `background-color` of cells.

Comment: You want to change color only on hovering a specific column? right?

Comment: @w3debugger . Right. You can see in my demo code. Change colour of text in the cell (a part of the specific column) instead of change colour of background in the cell (a part of specific column).

Comment: @Richard [This site](http://grammarist.com/spelling/color-colour/) says, "Both spellings are many centuries old. _Color_, now regarded as the American spelling, in fact predates the United States by several centuries. In early use the spellings vied for ascendancy with several other spellings. _Colur_, _culoure_, and _coolor_, for instance, were all in the mix before the modern British spelling gained permanent prevalence (...)"

Comment: @MrLister The etemology of English is complex, but definitely off topic here (and, as I thought would be obvious, there was a large amount of tongue in check in that comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `className` to all `td` elements at `event.target` `.cellIndex` at `mouseover` event, remove the `className` from all `td` elements at `mouseleave` event

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll("td");

var elemParents = document.querySelectorAll("tr")

for (var td of elems) {
  td.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
    var index = e.target.cellIndex;
    for (let tr of elemParents) {
      tr.querySelectorAll("td")[index]
      .className = "color";
    }
  });
  td.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(e) {
    for (let tr of elemParents) {
      for (var cell of tr.querySelectorAll("td")) {
        cell.className = "";
      }
    }
  })
}

function firefoxFix() {

  if (/firefox/.test(window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())) {

    var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

    for (var index = 0; index < tds.length; index++) {
      tds[index].innerHTML = '<div class="ff-fix">' + tds[index].innerHTML + '</div>';
    };

    var style = '<style>' + 'td { padding: 0 !important; }' + 'td:hover::before, td:hover::after { background-color: transparent !important; }' + '</style>';
    document.head.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', style);

  };

};

firefoxFix();
```

```css
.color {
  color: orange;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}
td,
th,
.ff-fix {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
td:hover::after,
.ff-fix:hover::after {
  background-color: blue;
  content: '\00a0';
  height: 10000px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5000px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>27</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>24</td>
      <td>26</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>25</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>24</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Simple answer and useful. You save my life. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The better approach I think, is to add class to html element when user is using firefox. You may use anonymous function for that, for example:

`(function(html) {
    if ( /firefox/.test( window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase() ) ) {
        html.classList.add('is-firefox');
    }
})(document.documentElement);`

Then you can add css for that class:

`.is-firefox td {
  color: orange;
}`

Working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cwxb1dfj/). Tested in Chrome 54 & Firefox 45.

You can try also this css fix without any javascript, like that:

`@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    td {
      color: orange;
    }
}`

Here you have some more information about CSS hacks:
https://www.wired.com/2010/02/browser-specific_css_hacks/

Comment: I write it working all in the browser except IE 9-. And I tried your code but it not working.

Comment: seem not working. I tried your fiddle. It only shows a text: `Test`. I don't think this mean?

Comment: Yes. 'Test' is black on Chrome and Orange on Firefox. Changing color on firefox was your problem?

Comment: I understand. You seem to mistake; I don't distinguish between Chrome or Firefox. I only want: when the user hovers on specific columns it auto highlights text of this column to orange. Currently, I only change success background-color. Are you understand my problems? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hello Try This One Below

```js
$('td').hover(function() {
    var t = parseInt($(this).index()) + 1;
    $('td:nth-child(' + t + ')').addClass('highlighted');
},
function() {
    var t = parseInt($(this).index()) + 1;
    $('td:nth-child(' + t + ')').removeClass('highlighted');
});
```

```css
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
    width: 40px;  
    height: 40px;
}

.highlighted {
    color:orange;
    background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>aa</td>
        <td>aa</td>
         <td>aa</td>
        <td>aa</td>
       
  </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>aa</td>
        <td>aa</td>
         <td>aa</td>
        <td>aa</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>aa</td>
        <td>aa</td>
         <td>aa</td>
        <td>aa</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>aa</td>
        <td>aa</td>
         <td>aa</td>
        <td>aa</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: He said column bro.

Answer (score 0):

You can call function on every cell hover like this :

```
function a(ele){              //On mouse over
ele.style.color = 'orange'; 
}

function b(ele){             // On mouse out
ele.style.color = 'grey';
}
```

Comment: What mean? I think you should add more code give your answer is clear.